# Edit and delete buttons not showing up on the page

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code in my component.html. All objects are shown on the page except for the column "actions" ergo the buttons edit and delete are not there. Why would that be ? No errors on the console. I am using `"@angular/material": "^7.3.0"`. Thank you.

```
<div>
  <br>
  <mat-card>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/add"> Create New Book </button>
    <br><br>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <br>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="books">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Book Id</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.title}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="editBook(element.id)">Edit </button>
          <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="deleteBook(element.id)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    </table>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Just making sure: `actions` is included in `displayedColumns`?

Comment: Added actions to displayedColumns and the column show up now. Thank you @p4r1

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to ensure that the array assigned to `*matHeaderRowDef` contains the column names that should be displayed. Column names are assigned with the `matColumnDef` directive.